# Attemping to Update OS from Shell Script causes an error

Tags: shell-script, raspbian

I'm currently attempting to build a shell script for automatically running a series of commands which would take a fresh Raspbian Image, and install all the updates, packages, etc, which I usually require.

To start the script, I'm running the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Updating OS..."

OUTPUT=$(sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade)
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "Done"
    else
        echo "**********ERROR**********"
        echo "$OUTPUT"
        exit 3
    fi
```

When this runs, I get the following output:

```
Updating OS...E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 2395 (apt-get)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
**********ERROR**********
Hit:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Reading package lists...
```

I've attempted to run the two commands one after another, but the output is the same anyway... The next set of commands in the shell script are making use of dpkg, but I was under the impression that it wouldn't be running continuing until the update was completely finished.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm new to shell scripting so apologies if this is very simple.

Comment: "... is another process using it?"

Comment: Okay so it's just fixed itself, I guess I was just assuming I was doing something wrong as I'm still learning shell scripting. Thanks for looking at this for me anyway!

Comment: If the update is already done it just shows 'Done', though I probably need to implement a case for 'Skipped'. Other than that it seems to be working as expected.

Comment: You should also capture stderr into the output command: `OUTPUT=$( { sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade; } 2>&1)`

Comment: Okay, I'll implement this into my script, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems that a background process was simply using the resources which was required by the script, and the issue wasn't with the script itself.